# Why are mat1, mat2, mat3, etc. defined and equal to 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm writing a formula in Excel (Microsoft 365) using the LAMBDA function and happened to name a variable `mat1`. This resulted in an error and I noticed that the name `mat1` was a different colour. I tried writing `=mat1` in a cell and weirdly it's equal to 0, rather than causing a value error as expected.

I checked the name manager and it's empty, and the workbooks doesn't have macros enabled. I also noticed that `mat2`, `mat3`, etc. are all equal to 0, as are `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`, etc.

Why are these variables defined?

Comment: `MAT1` , `MAT2` or `MAT3` etc are cell references hence why you can't use them as defined names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above prior to any answers posted hence posted the same as an answer:

[image]

As per excel naming rules one cannot define names ranges like cell references. That is, you can't give the name `A1` or `AA1` to a range, therefore `MAT1` , `MAT2`, `MAT3` etc are cell references, you need to use someother naming conventions.

---

**What one can do while naming defined names:**

*A name must begin with a letter, underscore (_), or backslash (). If a name begins with anything else, Excel will throw an error.*

---

Answer (score 1):

Use `mat_1` instead or some other name. Defined names shall not be the same as cell addresses.